# How to change this table layout to a css layout?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I created a `skinny` CSS class that has no margin, padding or border:

```
.skinny
{
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:0 0 0 0;
}
```

And I applied it to a row containing an image which also has the `skinny` class applied to it:

```
<td width="33%" align="center" class="skinny">
    <table width="400px" height="180px" class="skinny">
        <tr class="skinny">
            <td class="skinny" width="60px" height="100px"><a class="skinny" href="/"><img class="skinny" width="60px" height="100px" id="snapshot" src="/images/snapshot.png"></a></td>
            <td class="skinny" width="120px" height="100px"><a class="skinny" href="/"><h1 class="skinny">Product</h1></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

I'm trying to get the image to appear as close as possible to the `<h1>` text in the next cell so that they are pushed up against each other, left-to-right.

But no matter how many elements I apply the `skinny` class to, there seems to be something like a 'padding' around each of the table cells that creates a space between the image and the text.

What would I need to do to make this a CSS layout that puts the image directly to the left of the text with no space between them?

I tried this:

```
<td width="33%" align="center" class="skinny">
    <div class="skinny" width="60px" height="100px"><a class="skinny" href="/"><img class="skinny" width="60px" height="100px" id="snapshot" src="/images/snapshot.png"></a></div>
    <div class="skinny" width="120px" height="100px"><a class="skinny" href="/"><h1 class="skinny">Product</h1></a></div>
</td>
```

But it puts the image on top of the text.

Comment: Don't you have to write `0px` instead of `0`?

Comment: @thejh: nope. Zero is zero. `0px` is the same as `0em` or `0cm`, so you can (and arguably should) just write `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original layout, change the width of the second td to `*`. What's happening is that the table, and so the row, has a fixed amount of width to fill, and the layout engine is sharing it between the cells.

If you want to use the divs, then as Sebastian says, use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Bingo! The asterisk worked! Now, would you mind explaining what that did? :) Is it saying "take whatever space is left over after the first td"?

Comment: Do not attempt to penetrate the mysteries of the sacred asterisk!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
table.skinny { border-collapse:collapse; }
```

EDIT: IF you have a lone image in a td,  `display:block` will get rid of the descender space.

Also, you can mess with the `line-height` of the `h1` and set it to `1` or something.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
div.skinny {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/qAjkv/

Answer (score 0):

Does this do anything?

```
table.skinny {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

And although it’s off-topic, several zeroes have the same effect as just one zero:

```
.skinny
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

.skinny
{
    float:right
}